# How to create an SharePoint Calendar All Day Event using Graph API

Tags: api, events, graph, calendar

Is it possible to create an event as all day using a HTTP request to the graph API?
I'm sending a request similar to the below which creates the event successfully if i leave out the fAllDayEvent, if i leave it in i'm getting a non descript 500 error.

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteID}/lists/{listID}/items  {
 "fields": {
     "Title": "Test 1",
     "EventDate": "2021-04-04 00:00",
     "EndDate": "2021-04-04 00:00",
     "fAllDayEvent": "true"
} }
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this issue, the true value need to be boolean true rather than string true, this will work;

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteID}/lists/{listID}/items  {
 "fields": {
     "Title": "Test 1",
     "EventDate": "2021-04-04 00:00",
     "EndDate": "2021-04-04 00:00",
     "fAllDayEvent": true
} }
```